# References with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Sorry if this is the umpteenth post about references; I've read quite a few but can't seem to solve my problem, so here it goes. I want to reference articles by storing all article descriptions in a seperate file.

I have two files in a folder: references.bib and test.tex.

references.bib looks like this:

```
  @article{fasshauer2011positive,
  title={Positive definite kernels: past, present and future},
  author={Fasshauer, Gregory E},
  journal={Dolomite Research Notes on Approximation},
  volume={4},
  pages={21--63},
  year={2011}
  }
```

test.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Please just be a nice citation: \cite{fasshauer2011positive}.

\newpage

\bibliography{references} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

But this turns `\cite{fasshauer2011positive}` into `[?]` and makes me slightly angry. So who could help me? :D

Cheers.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX after LaTeX?

Comment: I knew I'd feel stupid when someone gave me the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the bibtex file.

The first time you compile the `.tex`, let's say, by running 
`pdflatex test.tex`, the [?] sign will be add to every unknown reference.

Then you need to run `bibtex test` in order to provide the information about what to put in the place of the [?]

After that, you must run two more times the `pflatex test.tex`:
The first will generate a list with the references in use (which will appear at the end of the file or at the end of the page, depending on the style you choose on `\bibliographystyle`), and the second will finally fill the [?] marks with the citation to the reference.